Using the Crayfish extension in the modeler
I'm trying to use the crayfish plug in in modeler to convert a file.
The model returns an error message.
It turns out that the grib fish extension seems to generate two files.
I deduce that my model does not know how to create two output files.
How do I load the layers in qgis from the ontenu link?



